# With an iOS custom renderer, is there a way I can make a question mark item appear in a TextCell and open up a dialog box?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML

```
<TableSection Title="Application">
   <TextCell x:Name="appUpdated" Text="Updated" />
   <TextCell x:Name="appVersion" Text="Application Version" />
</TableSection>
```

This C#:

```
public InfoPage()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   appUpdated.Text = AS.appUpdated;
   appVersion.Text = AS.appVersion;
}
```

Is there a way that I can make a small question mark appear to the right of the Text and have clicking on that open up a dialog with an explanation?

Please note I am looking for an iOS solution with a custom renderer.  I did before find some references about this but can't find examples any more.

Comment: Use a ViewCell instead, and add the Image with a TappedGestureRecognizer attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this [sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/customrenderers/viewcell/)

Also need **ViewCellRenderer** and a little change.

- replace the **CellImageView** in **NativeiOSCell** from **UIImageView** to **UIButton**, because we need click event to open a dialog box and show the info.
- add button click event to show the additional info

  ```
  CellImageView = new UIButton();
  CellImageView.TouchUpInside += delegate
  {
      UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView()
      {
          Title = HeadingLabel.Text,
          Message = SubheadingLabel.Text
      };
      alert.AddButton("OK");
      alert.Show();
  };
  ```
- modify the way how button get the image

  ```
  CellImageView.SetBackgroundImage(GetImage(cell.ImageFilename),UIControlState.Normal);
  ```
- adjust the frame of text and image.

  ```
  public override void LayoutSubviews()
  {
      base.LayoutSubviews();
      HeadingLabel.Frame = new CGRect(5, 4, ContentView.Bounds.Width - 63, 25);
      CellImageView.Frame = new CGRect(ContentView.Bounds.Width - 63, 5, 33, 33);
  }
  ```

This is my test.
[image]

#### **PS:** If you still have any confusions about my answer, I will try to upload a demo in github.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Sorry I just updated the question to mention that at this time I am looking for an iOS solution that uses a customer renderer.  I believe there's an iOS solution to this but can't seem to find it any more.